# C++ I have a template class that has a method print() that I need to act differently based on the type

Tags: c++, templates, typechecking

I know the point of templates is to generalize your code, however I would like one specific member function of that class to react differently based on what type of object was created. 
Specifically I created a Class Dictionary that is meant to be used to create DictionaryNoun or DictionaryAdjective objects. I have a Dictionary::print() that I want to have a code structure as follows:

```
Dictionary::print(){
   if(this is a Dictionary<Noun> object){
       // Print my nouns in some special way
   }
   if(this is a Dictionary<Adjective> object){
       // Print my adjectives in some special way
   }
   else{ //Print objects in default way}
}
```

My question is how do I do the type check on my objects?

Comment: I assume you meant to write `template<typename T> void Dictionary<T>::print(){...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ lets you specialize member functions for specific template arguments.  For example, if you have something like this:

```
template <typename T> class Dictionary {
    /* ... */
};
```

Then you can specialize what `print` does for a `Dictionary<Noun>` by writing

```
template <>
    void Dictionary<Noun>::print() {
    /* ... special code for printing nouns ... */
}
```

You can specialize for `Adjective` the same way.  Finally, you can write a default implementation that's used if neither matches by writing

```
template <typename T>
    void Dictionary<T>::print() {
    /* ... catch-all code ... */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: If the specializations are in a header they should be `inline`. If they are in an implementation file then you must provide a declaration in the header to disable the implicit instantiation. There are other potentially unwanted side effects to the specialization of member functions of the template, as the fact that after the specialization is encountered, you can no longer specialize the class.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use specializations to handle this, I believe that the design would be better if instead of that you implemented the actual printing in the elements (`Noun`, `Adjective`) Then have `Dictionary<T>::print` iterate over the container calling the appropriate overload/member function.

```
void print( std::ostream& o, Noun const & n );
void print( std::ostream& o, Adjective const & a );
// Alternatively
// void Noun::print( std::ostream& );
// void Adjective::print( std::ostream& );

template <typename T>
void Dictionary<T>::print( std::ostream& o ) {
   // iterate over all elements:
   for ( T const& r : container ) {
      print( o, r );
      // alternatively: r.print(o);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need templates for function (or method) overloading.

```
void print(std::ostream &os, const Noun &v) {}
void print(std::ostream &os, const Adjective &v) {}
```

Though you would need a template as a catch all.

```
template<typename T>
  void print(std::stream &os, const T &v) {}
```

Comment: +1 I don't understand the downvote. This answer makes much more sense than the accepted one. Just have `Dictionary<T>::print` forward the request to print each type of element to these external functions. This makes for simpler code to maintain in the future. Specializations for functions have *strange* side effects (for example, once you provide an specialization for a function, you can no longer specialize the class template)